# In-App Purchase Depending on Location

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Does the in-app popup changes currency depending on the location? 
For example: 
If i'm in the US the currency = $. 
If i'm in Japan the currency = ¥. 
If i'm in Germany the currency = €.

If yes, is this automatic (like apple handles it for you, you just have to register $ currency)?

If it's automatic, how can i test if it's working? I tried changing my location in the settings and the currency is still in $.

If it's not automatic, how do i enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Not location, but depending on which country's App Store you are logged in, yes.

The pricing table for the different currencies is available in Apple's documentation (note that you choose pricing levels, not dollar amounts).